# How to publish a npm package for different environment?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on a npm package which will be deployed to npm registry. And the npm package has some hard coded variables which bind to a specific backend server. I have test server and production server running. Since the npm package has hard coded env related variables, I need two npm package one for test, one for production. How can I publish a test npm package to npm registry for testing against my test server? Does npm registry support any kind of test features?

Comment: Why not pass the configuration variables in to your package when it is used?

Comment: If you're asking because you want to test your npm module before publishing, then this article may help: https://medium.com/@the1mills/how-to-test-your-npm-module-without-publishing-it-every-5-minutes-1c4cb4b369be